# Must $\emptyset$ be an element of any basis for a topology?

Tags: general-topology

Say $B$ is a basis for the topology $O$ on some set $X$.  Then, must we have $\emptyset \in B$ ?

If not, then how does one get $\emptyset \in O$ from taking the union of non-empty sets of $B$ ?

My definition of a basis for a topology is

> a collection $B$ of open sets is a *basis* for the topology, if every open set of the topology is a union of elements of $B$.

Comment: This is not the definition of a base for a topology with which I am familiar---my recollection is that a base for a topology is a collection $\cal{B}$ of subsets of $X$ which covers $X$ and has the property that if $B_1, B_2 \in \cal{B}$ and $x \in B_1 \cap B_2$, then there is some $B \in \cal{B}$ such that $x \in B \subseteq B_1 \cap B_2$.

Comment: I would say that the empty set should never be an element of a basis of topology.

Comment: Such a base generates a topology in the "obvious" way, i.e. every set in the topology generated by such a base can be written as a union of base sets, but this property is not what defines a base.  I am intentionally being a little imprecise here, but if we adopt the convention that $$\bigcup_{j \in \varnothing} B_j = \varnothing, $$ this should be correct.

Comment: @MoisheKohan So are you saying that the statement $\emptyset \in O$ follows vacuously from the definition of a basis?

Comment: I'm voting to reopen because Moishe's link did not answer my question.  Which is "must the $∅$ be an element of any basis for a topology?"

Comment: @Stephen: That's right: $\cup_{i\in \emptyset} A_i =\emptyset$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks.

Comment: @Stephen Your definition of a base for a topology appears to be incorrect.  You have not addressed that issue.  Once you address that issue, the answer to your question is almost certainly "You can either include the emptyset, or not.  It doesn't matter."

Comment: @XanderHenderson See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(topology)

Comment: @Stephen Your link basically says *exactly* what I said in my first two comments, which you have yet to address.

Comment: @XanderHenderson The very first sentence of my link is $ $  " **In mathematics, a base (or basis) $B$ for a topological space $X$ with topology $T$ is a collection of sets in $X$ such that every open set in $X$ can be written as a union of elements of $B$** ".  You're not wrong, but your definition is equivalent to mine.

Comment: The lede sentence in the Wikipedia article describes a *property* of a base for a topology.  This is not the definition, and is wrong as a definition.  For example, let $X = \{a, b\}$, and give $X$ the trivial topology, i.e. $\mathcal{T} = \{ \varnothing, X\}$.  Let $B = \{\varnothing, \{a\}, \{b\}\}$.  By your "definition", $B$ is a base for the topology $\mathcal{T}$ on $X$, as every set in $\mathcal{T}$ can be expressed as the union of sets in $B$.

Comment: @XanderHenderson  Correct, but it's also a basis according to your formulation of the definition.

Comment: @Stephen It is a base for *a* topology on $X$, but it is not a base for the topology $\mathcal{T}$.  However, by your definition, it *is* a base for the topology $\mathcal{T}$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102178/discussion-between-xander-henderson-and-stephen).